# Using decorators as class attributes instead of instance attributes

Tags: python

I have the following classes.

`Validator` is a decorator that receives a class which defines validation criteria for a decorated function. `ValidateKeys` is the validation criteria for this example. `Node2D` is a class using validation criteria.

```
class Validator(object):
    def __init__(self, TheValidator, *args, **kwargs):
        self.validator = TheValidator(*args,**kwargs)
    def __call__(self,f):
        def wrapped_f(instance, *args,**kwargs):
            self.TheValidator(instance, *args, **kwargs)
            return f(instance,*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapped_f

class ValidateKeys(object):
    def __init__(self,*keysIterable):
        self.validkeys = keysIterable
    def __call__(self, instance, **kwargs):
        for a in kwargs:
            if not a in self.validkeys:
                raise Exception()
        instance.__dict__.update(kwargs)

class Node2D(object):
    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__dict__
    @coords.setter
    def coords(self,Coords):
        self.set_coords(**Coords)
    @Validator(ValidateKeys, 'x','y')
    def set_coords(self,**Coords):
        pass
```

From what I understand, as things are written here, every instance of `Node2D` will produce a duplicate `Validator` (as will any other class decorated with `Validator`) and `ValidateKeys`.

*EDIT: [THIS IS WRONG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653422/using-decorators-as-class-attributes-instead-of-instance-attributes#comment41910400_26653422)!* See answer below.

Note that this is primarily a learning exercise for me and although I would be interested in hearing criticisms/suggestions for improving my over all approach, my primary goal is to learn more about how to use decorators effectively.

Also note that I normally would not use capitalization for a decorator class but am using it here since it makes it easier to read on SO.

Comment: This might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com. I will note this: `Validator` is a class with only two methods, one of which is `__init__`; it should probably just be a function instead. (See the talk ["Stop Writing Classes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) from PyCon 2012.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, not a specific problem.

Comment: I will remove the part about getting rid of duplicate class definitions then. The part about making `Validator` etc into a class object is very specific.

Comment: All your questions are about improving working code, not fixing code that doesn't work. Plus, the questions are broad and open-ended, whose answers might invite opinion-based answers. All of this makes it off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Especially as it's not even true that each instance would get a new instance of the validators. Decorators are evaluated at define time, not on instantiation. You could easily verify this by putting logging in the decorator `__init__` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about method vs class. It's a good one. I chose a class to define my decorator because I find the syntax for defining decorators using methods too confusing.

Comment: @Daniel: Hmmmm.... well, I guess you're right! Now to check if there will only be 1 list of validkeys per class. If so, this question is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I apologize to all for wasting your time! I don't have a problem here. My only excuse is I'm quite a python newbie (and new to coding in general). Should I close the question?

Comment: I meant, all the questions posted above, not all your questions on the site.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption was incorrect.

As things are written, only one instance of `Validator` and `ValidateKeys` is created per class. I did not realize that the line `@Validator(ValidateKeys, 'x','y')` only runs once (at the time of class definition) and not at instance creation.

I *should* have realized this, since decorator expressions appear at the same level of hierarchy as [class attributes](http://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide), e.g.:

```
class MyClass():
    class_attribute = None #only one class_attribute is created
    @decorator             #only one decorator (i.e., decorated method) is created
    def method():
        pass
```

Test:

```
class Validator(object):
    def __init__(self, TheValidator, *args, **kwargs):
        print("New Validator Object")
        self.TheValidator = TheValidator(*args,**kwargs)
    def __call__(self,f):
        def wrapped_f(instance, *args,**kwargs):
            self.TheValidator(instance, *args, **kwargs)
            return f(instance,*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapped_f

class ValidateKeys(object):
    def __init__(self,*keysIterable):
        print("New ValidateKeys Object")
        self.validkeys = keysIterable
    def __call__(self, instance, **kwargs):
        for a in kwargs:
            if not a in self.validkeys:
                raise Exception()
        instance.__dict__.update(kwargs)

class Node2D(object):
    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__dict__
    @coords.setter
    def coords(self,Coords):
        self.set_coords(**Coords)
    @Validator(ValidateKeys, 'x','y')
    def set_coords(self,**Coords):
        pass

n1 = Node2D()
n2 = Node2D()
n1.setcoords(x=1,y=2)
n1.coords
```

Output:

```
'New Validator Object'    #<-- Seen only once when module is loaded (class defined)
'New ValidateKeys Object' #<-- Seen only once when module is loaded (class defined)
'{'x': 1, 'y': 2}'
```

I do not have the problem I thought I had. Thanks to all for the help.